# Bacon.js call function every time element loses focus

Tags: bacon.js

**Update** I think I might have it figured out. I was using an old bacon.js version, which might have been part of the problem. I'll update later as I figure out if I have it. Here's the partially working version: http://cdpn.io/yfxDA

I'm trying to call a function every time an element loses focus (an `input` but in the below example I'm using a `div`).

[This is what I tried](http://jsfiddle.net/jon49/PG4c4/42/):

```
var $on = $('div')
$on.asEventStream('focusout').subscribe(alert('no!'))
```

and

```
var $on = $('div')
$on.asEventStream('focusout').onValue(alert('no!'))
```

They both work the first time but then stop working. Is there a way to get this to work?

Eventually I would like to merge `focusin`/`focusout` and perform a side-effect.

Comment: You may not have realised, but your alerts are being executed on the parse phase. I mean, onValue takes a function definition: onValue(function(){alert('no!');});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I just needed the most up to date version of the software. Here's what the code looks like now:

```
var $on = $('div')
var $h = $('div input')
var d = 'contains'

$h.val(d)
var f = function(arg){
  return ($h.val() === d) ? '' : d
} 

$on.asEventStream('focusout').merge($on.asEventStream('focusin')).toProperty().assign($h, 'val', f)
```

Answer (score 0):

I works just fine with the latest version:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xLHyq

Comment: I -1 the question because is not useful anymore. Also check out my comment on the question itself. Your sample code has a silly mistake that adds to your confusion analysing the issue.